# znapzend systemd service and command line arguments

Tags: znapzend

I'm starting znapzend using the included systemd unit file and I'm wondering if there's any way, short of editing the unit file and changing the ExecStart command line, to specify runtime options for znapzend.  Specifically, I want to add "--features=compressed --autoCreation".  Does znapzend read any runtime options from a configuration file (e.g. /etc/sysconfig/znapzend)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit `/etc/default/znapzend`.  If that doesn't exist, copy the `znapzend.default` file (available [on github](https://github.com/oetiker/znapzend/blob/master/init/znapzend.default)) to `/etc/default/znapzend` first.

You'll need znapzend version 0.19 or later in order for this to work.